# How to view current database schema for Heroku app in Terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, terminal, schema

I am trying to view my Heroku app's schema in Terminal (Mac OS X Lion) and stumbled upon a command that does just that. In Terminal, I run `heroku run more db/schema.rb` but it seems to display an older schema version. I just migrated the Heroku db and I noticed that none of the new columns are listed.

I can't seem to find anything helpful in Heroku's documentation. Does anyone know a command to view the current database schema for a Heroku app?

By the way, I inherited the code for the app and for some reason all of the migration files are commented out (there are probably 40+ files) so I can't just run `rake db:migrate` locally to update the schema; hence, I'd like to see the Heroku app's schema directly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could run `heroku pg:psql` to fire up a Postgres console, then issue `\d` to see all tables, and `\d tablename` to see details for a particular table.

Comment: To exit, type 'q' and hit enter.

Comment: I had to use \q to exit.

Answer (score 34):

For a rails schema, try:

```
$ heroku run "bundle exec rake db:schema:dump && cat db/schema.rb"
```

Comment: The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake) state that "Rake tasks that write to disk, such as rake db:schema:dump, are not compatible with Heroku’s ephemeral filesystem." Won't this command fail?

Comment: It works. You can rely on the file existing for the while the `run` dyno is up, which is inherently long enough for it to be `cat`'d.

Comment: Best answer: It copies the full Heroku schema to your terminal

Comment: This is it. Thanks so much for answering this. I realized that my schema on heroku isn't matching the most updated version of my schema. I took two steps to make them match. I double checked it by running `heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate:status -a application-name` which showed me that my most recent migration was down. Then, I ran `heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate -a application-name` to run that migration! Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: To whoever like me thought this could affect the app, it doesn't bother production files.
You'll need to collect the result of the cat dump and that'll be your schema.rb

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rateaux](http://rubygems.org/gems/rateaux):

```
rake db:view:schema
```